# Org mode link to open xterm with arguments

Tags: org-mode

```
* MyHeader
My links:

Working:
[[elisp:(term "xterm")]]

**Not working**
[[elisp:(term "xterm visidata /tmp/foo.csv")]]
```

1. [X] Open xterm from org mode link
2. [ ] Open xterm from org mode link **with arguments**

How can I append arguments to the terminal command?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What about `src_screen{echo "hello"}` or `src_bash{<something>}`?

Comment: @mankoff I need a new frame/window opened with the cli-app launched. Offtopic: Searching `emacs "src_screen"` returned three (irrelevant) results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `term` does what you think it does: if you want to open an external `xterm` window running `visidata /tmp/foo.csv`, then you want to run the elisp expression:

```el
(shell-command "xterm -e visidata /tmp/foo.csv &")
```

so your link should look like `[[elisp:(shell-command "xterm -e visidata /tmp/foo.csv &")]]`.

EDIT: as the commenters indicate, the command needs to be run asynchronously, otherwise emacs waits for the command to finish and will not do anything else. That can be done, as the OP indicates in their comment, with `start-process`, but it can also be done, perhaps more simply, with `shell-command`,  by adding an `&` at the end of the command (see the edited code above), which is how you run a shell command in the background. `C-h f shell-command` has all the details.

Comment: Got infinite `executing Emacs-Lisp code block...`. Though you lead me to this working line: `(start-process "" nil "/usr/bin/xterm" "-e" "visidata" "/tmp/foo.csv")`

Comment: I can confirm what @412p9wej mentioned: Using `shell-command` on an Org Mode link results in Emacs freezing, while using `start-process` does open a terminal window. I tried this with the following links: `[[elisp:(shell-command "st")]]` and `[[elisp:(start-process "st" nil "st")]]`.